# HTML5 Canvas: Use context.isPointInPath(x, y) for complex shapes with more paths

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

I am drawing a complex shape, that consists of 6 thin lines and two thick line.

In the code i am opening 8 pathes to do this:

```
        context.save();
    context.lineWidth=2;
    var TAB_ABSTAND=10;
    var TAB_SAITENZAHL=6;
    var TAB_SEITENDICKE=10;
    for(var i=0;i<TAB_SAITENZAHL;i++)
    {
         context.beginPath();
         context.moveTo(this.clickedX, this.clickedY+(i*TAB_ABSTAND));
         context.lineTo(this.clickedX+this.width, this.clickedY+(i*TAB_ABSTAND));
         context.stroke();  
    }



     context.lineWidth=TAB_SEITENDICKE;

     context.beginPath();
     context.moveTo(this.clickedX, this.clickedY-1);
     context.lineTo(this.clickedX, this.clickedY+TAB_ABSTAND*(TAB_SAITENZAHL-1)+1);
     context.stroke();

     context.beginPath();
     context.moveTo(this.clickedX+this.width, this.clickedY-1);
     context.lineTo(this.clickedX+this.width, this.clickedY+TAB_ABSTAND*(TAB_SAITENZAHL-1)+1);
     context.stroke();    

     context.restore();
```

In the canvas onmousedown event i want to recognize if the shape (or one of the other shapes in an array) have been clicked to realize a dragging.

Is there a way to use the isPointInPath(x,y) Method to recognize if one of the Lines in the "Shape" has been clicked?

What i want to do is to implement a mechanism that maintains a list of draggable objects.

What i found out yet:

1.) beginPath is the only context method that interrupts the path in a way, that the previous path is not recognized by the isPointInPath method

2.) On a single line with big stroke (i.e. context.lineWidth=10) the isPointInPath method is not returning true when it is just a single line without curves

3.) closePath draws the endpoint of the last line to the beginning point of the first line, but it is not interupting the path, so that a later stroke() always takes effect on the lineTo and moveTo-methods before the closePath

4.) It seems to be impossible to draw a bigger line without calling beginPath() without stroking the rest of the pathes

5.) moveTo(x,y) really jumps to another position, but the other position can be a path that returns true for the isPointInPath method, when it not only consists of one line (see 1.)).

6.) To visualize pathes the fill() method is usefull

So should i always use rectangles to draw lines when i want to recognize if the "line" (that is drawn as rect) is in Path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**How to hit-test a shape made of multiple paths**

This shape is made up of 2 paths: *Path1= 4 thin red lines, Path2= 2 thick blue lines.*

[image]

**First, here is information about Paths that explain why your observations occured**

> `beginPath` is the only context method that interrupts the path in a
>   way, that the previous path is not recognized by the isPointInPath
>   method

You can define multiple paths, but `isPointInPath` will only test the *last defined path*.

A path consists of a *set of path commands* formed like this:

- A path begins with the `beginPath` command
- Then a path defines its shape with `moveTo`, `lineTo`, etc commands.
- A path ends with the next `beginPath` command.

So in your question code, only this last moveTo+lineTo would be tested.

```
 context.beginPath();
 context.moveTo(this.clickedX+this.width, this.clickedY-1);
 context.lineTo(this.clickedX+this.width, this.clickedY+TAB_ABSTAND*(TAB_SAITENZAHL-1)+1);
```

> On a single line with big stroke (i.e. context.lineWidth=10) the isPointInPath method is not returning true when it is just a single
>   line without curves.

Mathematically, a line occupies no space. Therefore you cannot test if any point is "In" a single line.

In most browsers (notably NOT IE/Edge), you can use the new `isPointInStroke` method to test if a point is inside a single line. For cross-browser compatibility you would have to "fatten" a single line into a path so that you can hit-test a point within that fattened path.

> `closePath` draws the endpoint of the last line to the beginning point
>   of the first line, but it is not interupting the path, so that a later
>   stroke() always takes effect on the lineTo and moveTo-methods before
>   the closePath

IMHO, `closePath` is poorly named. It does not close (does not complete) a path. It is not the "closing brace" to beginPath's "opening brace". Instead, it simply draws a line directly from the current point in the path back to the first point in the path.

> It seems to be impossible to draw a bigger line without calling
>   beginPath() without stroking the rest of the pathes

You are only allowed one style to apply to one path. So if you define multiple lineWidths inside a set of path commands then the last lineWidth wins and the entire path will be stroked with that last linewidth.

> `moveTo(x,y)` really jumps to another position, but the other position
>   can be a path that returns true for the isPointInPath method, when it
>   not only consists of one line (see 1.)).

`moveTo` is the equivalent of "picking up your pen" and moving it to a new location on the paper *without ending the current set of path commands*.

For example: Assume you begin a path with `beginPath` and then draw 3 separated triangles using `moveTo` to separate them. Then all 3 triangles will be included in the path and all 3 triangles will be tested with `isPointInPath`.

> To visualize pathes the fill() method is useful

`.fill` and `.stroke` will command the context to visually draw the current path onto the canvas. They do not complete the path -- only the next `beginPath` will complete the current path. So if you define 2 sides of a triangle, stroke(), define the 3rd side of the triangle and stroke() again, then the first 2 sides will be stroked twice and the 3rd side will be stroked once.

*Important information:* You can define a path and test it with `isPointInPath` without actually stroking (or filling) the test path. This means you can individually *redefine + `isPointInPath`* each of your paths without having to redraw them on the canvas. You can also define a single shape that is made up of multiple paths and hit-test that multiple-path-shape using isPointInPath.

So to test which of your shapes (shapes==paths) inside the mousedown event, you can redefine each multi-path and test it with `context.isPointInPath(mouseX,mouseY)`.

To actually draw your shape, you need multiple styles (thin vs thick lines) so you will have to **draw** the paths individually since you only get 1 styling per path.

**Here's example code and a Demo:**

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;
function reOffset(){
  var BB=canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
  offsetX=BB.left;
  offsetY=BB.top;        
}
var offsetX,offsetY;
reOffset();
window.onscroll=function(e){ reOffset(); }
window.onresize=function(e){ reOffset(); }

var isDown=false;
var startX,startY;

var shapes=[];
//
var path1=[
  {x:150,y:100},
  {x:50,y:100},
  {x:25,y:75},
  {x:50,y:50},
  {x:150,y:50}
];
path1.linewidth=1;
path1.strokestyle='red';
//
var path2=[
  {x:150,y:50},
  {x:225,y:75},
  {x:150,y:100}
];
path2.linewidth=5;
path2.strokestyle='blue';

var shape1=[path1,path2];
shape1.fill='green';
//
shapes.push(shape1);

// draw both parts of the path onto the canvas
draw(path1);
draw(path2);

$("#canvas").mousedown(function(e){handleMouseDown(e);});

function define(shape){
  ctx.beginPath();
  for(j=0;j<shape.length;j++){
    var p=shape[j];
    ctx.moveTo(p[0].x,p[0].y);
    for(var i=1;i<p.length;i++){
      ctx.lineTo(p[i].x,p[i].y);
    }
  }
}
//
function draw(path){
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(path[0].x,path[0].y);
  for(var i=1;i<path.length;i++){
    ctx.lineTo(path[i].x,path[i].y);
  }
  ctx.lineWidth=path.linewidth;
  ctx.strokeStyle=path.strokestyle;
  ctx.stroke();
}
//
function dot(x,y,fill){
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(x,y,2,0,Math.PI*2);
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.fillStyle=fill;
  ctx.fill();
}

function handleMouseDown(e){
  // tell the browser we're handling this event
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
  // get mouseX,mouseY
  var mx=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
  var my=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);
  //
  var dotcolor='red';
  for(var i=0;i<shapes.length;i++){
    define(shapes[i]);
    if(ctx.isPointInPath(mx,my)){dotcolor=shapes[i].fill;}
  }
  dot(mx,my,dotcolor);
}
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; }
#canvas{border:1px solid red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h4>Click inside and outside the multi-path shape<br>Inside clicks become green dots.</h4>
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
```

Comment: "but `isPointInPath` will only test the last defined path." Actually, in browsers supporting the [`Path2D()` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Path2D/Path2D), you can store your path as object, and apply it to the `isPointInPath` method as the first argument.

Comment: yeah I know, it's just that Path2D constructor is so appealing, I hope the list of supporting browsers grow fast and that we can finally use it. But I agree it shouldn't be part of your answer, just as a comment :P

Answer (score 0):

The following code is doing what i expect. I am using only fill() and never use beginPath()

```
    context.save();
context.lineWidth=1;
var TAB_ABSTAND=10;
var TAB_SAITENZAHL=6;
var TAB_SEITENDICKE=10;

for(var i=0;i<TAB_SAITENZAHL;i++)
{
    context.moveTo(this.clickedX+5, this.clickedY+(i*TAB_ABSTAND));
    context.lineTo(this.clickedX+this.width, this.clickedY+(i*TAB_ABSTAND));
    context.lineTo(this.clickedX+this.width, this.clickedY+(i*TAB_ABSTAND)+1);
    context.lineTo(this.clickedX+5, this.clickedY+(i*TAB_ABSTAND)+1);   
}

context.moveTo(this.clickedX, this.clickedY);
context.lineTo(this.clickedX, this.clickedY+TAB_ABSTAND*(TAB_SAITENZAHL-1)+1);
context.lineTo(this.clickedX+5, this.clickedY+TAB_ABSTAND*(TAB_SAITENZAHL-1)+1);
context.lineTo(this.clickedX+5, this.clickedY);

context.moveTo(this.clickedX+this.width, this.clickedY);
context.lineTo(this.clickedX+this.width, this.clickedY+TAB_ABSTAND*(TAB_SAITENZAHL-1)+1);
context.lineTo(this.clickedX+this.width-5, this.clickedY+TAB_ABSTAND*(TAB_SAITENZAHL-1)+1);
context.lineTo(this.clickedX+this.width-5, this.clickedY);
context.fill();    

context.restore();
```